# Neo4J on AWS t2.micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I'm learning neo4j and I'm planning to install it on an Amazon t2.micro.

However, in the aws marketplace, instances only start from t2.medium.
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Neo4j-Neo4j-Graph-Database-Community-Edition/B071P26C9D

How can I run neo4J on a t2.micro or are there other alternatives that also have a free tier?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subcribe to your free AWS t2.micro and install it by yourself. This is what I did before;

> 1. Subcribe to a free t2.micro tier up to 12-months.
> 2. Download the neo4j community edition [here](https://go.neo4j.com/download-thanks.html?edition=community&release=3.5.26&flavour=unix&_gl=1*17hurkn*_ga*OTg5MjU4NTI4LjE2MTU5ODM2NjY.*_ga_DL38Q8KGQC*MTYxNTk4MzY2NS4xLjAuMTYxNTk4MzY2NS4w&_ga=2.236338241.1770078764.1615983666-989258528.1615983666):

> 3. Upload the installation file to your AWS server
> 4. Install your neo4j and manage it yourself.